# Source of spontaneous symmetry breaking

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, potential, higgs, symmetry-breaking

In spontaneous symmetry breaking, one assumes a negative potential, i.e., $m^2\phi^2 \rightarrow -\mu^2 \phi^2$, for a scalar field $\phi$. One always starts with  this $-\mu^2\phi^2$ term in the Lagrangian.
What is the physical source of this negative potential?

Comment: "Is there any reasearch [sic] or literature available on this?" Yes, there's like a million different quantum field theory textbooks you could look at.

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/710915/

Answer (score 3):

What you need for spontaneous symmetry breaking - and not just in QFT - is an unstable equilibrium, i.e. a potential maximum. The term $-\mu^2 \phi^2$ is the most simple expression for such a situation. Much like the harmonic oscillator is the most generic potential minimum, changing the sign in the harmonic oscillator potential yields the most generic potential maximum. Not a "physical source" of the term, I would say, but probably the best explanation of why you'll find it in the Lagrangian. ;)